# Vuforia Development agreement issue in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I am using Vuforia Cloud Recognition in my project using **Unity 2017.3.f1** version and **Vuforia version 7.2**.

I had this project working fine few days ago but now it started giving Vuforia Developer agreement error.

> The Vuforia Developer Agreement needs to be accepted before using Vuforia in an application.

I even have this app on the playstore before but now the camera feed doesn't show up and gives this error.

I tried reimporting Vuforia asset, enabling/disabling Vuforia from XR settings but nothing helped.

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to open the _Vuforia Developer Portal_ and check if there is an update of the agreement to accept.

Comment: @Kerberos nothing is there

Answer (score 0):

In order to start using Vuforia Engine in Unity you simply need to accept a `Vuforia Developer Agreement` for getting a Valid License Key.

If an Agreement updates (or your License Key isn't valid) you'll need to reaccept Agreement again.

Go to [Vuforia Developer Portal](https://developer.vuforia.com/legal/vuforia-developer-agreement) and accept new Agreement.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in Vuforia 7.2 and is fixed in 7.5.26. In Unity Cloud Build this is still an issue though.

Source: https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/unity/license-agreement-error#comment-65963